# Watchdog Python - Fully downloaded file from Chrome is not observed

Tags: python, google-chrome, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have this piece of code from my program which basically checks if a file has been created & renamed so that it can move the file to another directory.

```py
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    @staticmethod
    def on_moved(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None
        time.sleep(5)
        move_file(event.dest_path, DESTINATION_FOLDER)
```

And it always errors out with chrome downloads:

```py
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\something\\Downloads\\Unconfirmed 116567.crdownload'
```

Is there any way to make Watchdog check for the **COMPLETED** download instead of the `.crdownload` file chrome creates when it starts the downloads?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the on_modified event instead. And also ignore the .crdownload files. With this, you will be able to track the finally renamed file (after download completion).

```
def wait_till_file_is_created(self, source_path):
    historicalSize = -1
    while (historicalSize != os.path.getsize(source_path)):
        historicalSize = os.path.getsize(source_path)
        time.sleep(1)

def on_modified(self, event):
    print('\nEvent type: modified; Source file: ', event.src_path)
    if '.crdownload' not in event.src_path:
        # wait for the file copy to be completed (add sleep or check size repeatedly with a delay)
        self.wait_till_file_is_created(event.src_path)
        # code to move file to the required path
```